# has codealike any security risks?

Tags: visual-studio, security, time-tracking

I want to install Codealike in my visual studio, to use in highly secured project, I wondered if there is any security risk, like code transfer and etc.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Codealike doesn't transfer any code to their servers. It only transfers via SSL the names of classes, files, methods, namespaces and projects. It also transfers statistical information to build the analysis models that allow to derive insights for users.

Codealike also has Enterprise deployments for teams that might be hosted on premises or over a private cloud.

Disclaimer: I work at Codealike.